# How to use xenomai API?

Tags: ubuntu, xenomai

I install xenomai-runtime on ubuntu 11.04.

Is that finish installing of xenomai?

I found that I can't find xenomai's kernel and boot from it.

So my question are:

1.How to boot xenomai's kernel?

2.How to write the simplest program "hello world" on xenomai API?

3.Where are full of xenomai's document or examples?

Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

Hey I am still a noob but to install xenomai go to the website [Xenomai](http://www.xenomai.org) and you can find the quick build steps there. They have not given the configuration there so you will have to search on the web for that.

here's a [link](http://www.blaess.fr/christophe/2011/12/28/xenomai-2-6-0-sur-ubuntu-11-10/) of use its in french(i can speak)still very helpful.
Also documentation you can install by going to the software center and typing xenomai you will find 3 packages one of which is the documentation. You can also install the xenomai libraries from there.

Comment: Can you turn off APM? I can't find it on linux kernel 2.6.38.8 instructed by that webpage. Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

- Installing Xenomai: http://www.xenomai.org/documentation/xenomai-2.6/README.INSTALL
- Xenomai API: http://www.xenomai.org/documentation/xenomai-2.6/html/api/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I created a Tiny OS for my controller(ARM), and installed Xenomai 2.60 on that OS. This Link explains well, How to install Xenomai in Operating system [Link1](http://www.blaess.fr/christophe/2011/12/28/xenomai-2-6-0-sur-ubuntu-11-10/), [Link2](http://www.xenomai.org/documentation/xenomai-2.6/html/README.INSTALL/). If you wanna Learn how This Xenomai works and what are the skins please refer this [Link](http://www.cs.ru.nl/lab/xenomai/exercises). It explains everything about Xenomai how to boot Kernal, Examples n all.